# Is possible get segment by member in mailchimp API 3.0?

Tags: mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am doing **integration** with `mailchimp-API-3.0`. I ran into a problem that I can not solve.

I already have members in my database imported from mailchimp via `Batch-API-3.0`. **After the import** they were segmented into the mailchimp.
Now I need to know in **which segments** a **member** is stored.

### At first I had thought of 2 alternatives.

- Search *the segment of a member*, but I did not find a resource for this.
- Search *for a member by segment*, but also did not find a resource for this.

I'm sorry if I could not see this in the mailchimp API. But do you have an idea if this is possible with the API-3.0 of mailchimp?

Answer (score 0):

There really is not a simple way via API to find a member thread. However, I was able to find a solution to my problem with `fields hidden` in the form.

Follow the tutorial for anyone who wants to do the same.

https://mailchimp.com/help/determine-webpage-signup-location/

From this tutorial I got an idea.

I **created a hidden field** with the `ID` of my `segment` and from that point I can do some things with the targeting API